# AngularJS checkbox and dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I wanted a example wherein i have a dropdown and checkbox. the field of checkboxes must be same as data in dropdown.

now when i select a value in dropdown it should tick / untick the coresponding option in the checkbox list

Comment: Mine this thing was not working properly.. was some binding problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selected">
        <option ng-repeat="x in names">{{x}}</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="selected" value="ABC">ABC<br>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="selected" value="DEF">DEF<br>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="selected" value="GHI">GHI<br>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["ABC", "DEF", "GHI"];
});
</script>
```